# Code Page choice in Configuration options for the IBM® Db2 Warehouse image

Tags: analytics, dashdb

It seems there is no option to choose code page between 1208 and 819 for DashDB Local. How can we setup a 819 code page BLUDB database ?

Best regards, JMB

Answer (score 0):

According to the [What's New in IBM Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, IBM Db2 Warehouse, and IBM Db2 on Cloud](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21961758) document, specifying a custom code page during container creation is possible with the September 29, 2017 update with the `DB_CODESET`, `DB_COLLATION_SEQUENCE` and `DB_TERRITORY` parameters that can be passed to `docker run`.